# Oracle check constraint1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column Hire_date in table x with data

```
01-jun-98

16-aug-99

02-feb-09

01-mar-06
-

01-dec-08

17-mar-99

16-feb-07
```

I was asked to create a check constraint on that Hire_date column. Check that the hire_date comes after 2000. I see an error
I tried again to check if the hire_date comes after 1996. The constraint was successfully created.
why did i see an error when i created a check constraint for hire_date>2000 ?

Code:

```
alter table x
add constraint check_hire_date check(hire_Date>'01-jan-2000')
```

got error

```
alter table x
add constraint check_hire_date check(hire_Date>'01-jan-1996')
```

successful

Comment: Ummm...  Isn't it obvious?  Some of the dates in your sample data, presumably, are before Jan 1, 2000.  I would assume, for example, that the "17-mar-99" row is March 17, 1999.  That would obviously fail the check constraint.

Comment: Got you...I am learning day by day....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got error is obvious. Some of your data violate the constraint. When you add a constraint to a table, it will validate the all data to the constraint.

You can use `novalidate` option to skip the validation. If you apply `novalidate` option when you create the constraint, you can add the constraint while you don't validate the old(=current) date with the constraint. The constraint will affect to the data which is inserted after the creation of the constraint.

```
sql> create table x (hire_date date);
sql> insert into x values ('1998-01-01');
sql> insert into x values ('2000-01-05');

sql> select * from x;

HIRE_DAT
--------
98/01/01
00/01/05

sql> alter table x add constraint d_check check 
  2  (hire_date >= to_date('2000-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
  3  novalidate;

sql> insert into x values ('1999-01-01');

insert into x values ('1999-01-01')
*
error at line 1:
check constraint (d_check check) violated
```